# Deriving an expression for the tangential velocity of a meteor orbiting the Earth? I have 2 expressions, not sure which is correct

Tags: homework-and-exercises, classical-mechanics, newtonian-gravity, kinematics, centripetal-force

**"A meteoroid of mass $m$ is on a circular Earth orbit of radius $R$ which is a few (> 2) times larger than the radius of the Earth $R_E$. Derive an expression for the meteoroid's speed. State the meaning of all symbols used."**

An online worked solution gave this answer, using Newton's Laws of Gravitation:

$M$ = mass of the Earth, $G$ = gravitational constant, $v$ = tangential velocity of meteorite.

$F = ma$

$F = \frac {GMm}{R^2} = \frac {mv^2}{R}$

$v = \frac {\sqrt {GM}}{R}$

Before I checked the solutions, I derived the following expression, using the formulae for circular motion:

$a$ = centripetal acceleration of meteorite, $\omega$ = angular speed of meteorite, $v$ = tangential velocity of meteorite.

$v = \omega R$

$\omega ^2 = \frac {a}{R}$

$\omega = \sqrt {\frac {a}{R}}$

$v = R \sqrt {\frac {a}{R}}$

$v = \sqrt {Ra}$

**Are both these solutions correct? If not, could someone please explain why the incorrect one is incorrect? Thank you.**

Question Source: https://www2.physics.ox.ac.uk/sites/default/files/2011-02-14/pat_2012_paper_pdf_10581.pdf, Question 21

Comment: I got down voted for some reason, maybe because it seems like this is a cheap homework question. It's not meant to be. The crux of the question is whether the two expressions are both equally valid, since they have been derived differently, or whether I have misunderstood the physics behind one of them. Knowing this will help give me a better understanding of the physics involved. Unfortunately, with no official mark scheme released for the test from which this question was sourced, forums like these are the only real way to check whether you were right or wrong, and why.

Comment: [This isn't a forum](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/92107/), it's a question and answer site.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well your answer is basically just solving velocity for circular motion if you're given acceleration.

The answer you linked to is using Newtons law of gravitation to actually determine the acceleration; so their answer is far more representative of the situation.  Your equation has a term "$a$" which we have no way to find.

Their answer relies only on values we were told we know (and the gravitational constant, which is just a constant so we know that).  Essentially, their answer takes the acceleration term from your answer and works out it's value based on Newtons law of gravitation.

To summarize; your answer isn't *wrong*; but it missed the point of the question.  The acceleration you used in your equation could be further broken down.

Comment: Thank you, perfect answer. I'm still getting the hang of derivation questions - this is a useful tip I'll make a note of. I will choose this as the solution.

Comment: @user2627595 It's usually bad practice to accept an answer so soon.  There could be 5 people responding after me saying how wrong I am.  (I don't think it will happen here, but just something to keep in mind; it's usually best to wait awhile before accepting)